# how to retrieve employee hierarchy without using connect by clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table test 
(
emp_id number ,
emp_name varchar2(10),
mgr_id number ) ;

insert into test values(1,'amar',null);

insert into test values(2,'ram',1);

insert into test values(3,'raju',2);

insert into test values(4,'vinod',3);

insert into test values(5,'amar1',null);

insert into test values(6,'ram1',5);

insert into test values(7,'raju1',6);

insert into test values(8,'vinod1',7);
```

now i want hierarchy of top level employee who has no manager . required comma seperated employee list

expected output :

```
| emp_id | emp_id_under_manager |

|1      |    2,3,4 |

|5      |    6,7,8 |
```

employee id 1 and 5 has no manager hence displayed only that 2 employees hierarchy

```
WITH RECURSIVE employee_paths (emp_id, emp_name, path) AS
(
  SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, CAST(e.emp_id AS CHAR(200))  
    FROM test e 
    WHERE mgr_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, CONCAT(ep.path, ',', e.emp_id)
    FROM employee_paths ep JOIN test  e
      ON ep.emp_id = e.mgr_id
)
SELECT * FROM employee_paths ORDER BY path;
```

getting error like missing keyword

Comment: You can use recursive CTE as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Did you get any errors ? Recursive queries is what you can use for this.

Comment: yes not getting desired output from recursive with clause query

Comment: @shubham - if you edit your question to include your query and the output you get from it, we can (hopefully) tell you why it isn't giving the results you expect.

Comment: sure, just added query but getting error in query @AlexPoole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> getting error like missing keyword

There isn't a `RECURSIVE` keyword; a CTE is made recursive by referring to itself in a union. The `concat()` function only takes two arguments in Oracle too, so you would need to nest calls or more simply use the concatenation operator. Casting the manager ID to `char(200)` also means that is padded with spaces, so when you concatenate you have a big gap; you can use `to_char()` instead of `cast()`:

```
WITH employee_paths (emp_id, emp_name, path) AS
(
  SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, to_char(e.emp_id)
    FROM test e 
    WHERE mgr_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, ep.path || ',' || e.emp_id
    FROM employee_paths ep JOIN test  e
      ON ep.emp_id = e.mgr_id
)
SELECT * FROM employee_paths ORDER BY path;
```

That still doesn't give you the output you want though...

```
EMP_ID EMP_NAME PATH   
------ -------- -------
     1 amar     1      
     2 ram      1,2    
     3 raju     1,2,3  
     4 vinod    1,2,3,4
     5 amar1    5      
     6 ram1     5,6    
     7 raju1    5,6,7  
     8 vinod1   5,6,7,8
```

If you just get the child ID in the recursive member you can use `listagg()` to get the comma-separated list:

```
with rcte (root_id, emp_id) as (
  select emp_id, emp_id
  from test
  where mgr_id is null
  union all
  select root_id, t.emp_id
  from rcte r
  join test t on t.mgr_id = r.emp_id
)
select root_id as emp_id,
  listagg(emp_id, ',') within group (order by emp_id) as emp_id_under_manager
from rcte
where emp_id != root_id
group by root_id
```

which with your sample data gets:

```
EMP_ID EMP_ID_UNDER_MANAGER
------ --------------------
     1 2,3,4
     5 6,7,8
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=73e2c6b55e9c5b2be6f9d1572d17ebd2) showing the recursive CTE with all output, then filtered and aggregated as above; and also showing the hierarchical query equivalent for info, and I've included your version and the corrected version (that doesn't error but gives wrong results, both with `cast()` and `to_char()`).